# How to know version of mongodb used to create .jar file?

Tags: java, mongodb, version

I got the jar file like **XXX.jar** and I changed it to **XXX.zip** Then
After extracting I could get that which java version used to create XXX.jar file.
But in that zip I can see -
*com->mongodb-> different folders and many more .class files*
And I want to know that on which mongodb version this XXX.jar file was created.

Comment: did you try to use Database MetaData?

Comment: Ok , I will try it As I got the version of java.

Answer (score 1):

You may look into the META-INF subfolder, there is MANIFEST.MF file, where you'll find the mongodb version.

Comment: Yes, you are right but while exporting jar in eclipse , If we select option as "Package required into generated jar" then only we see the mongodb version in MANIFEST.MF file but if we select "Extract required libraries into generated jar" then we can't see the mongodb version in MANIFEST.MF file .

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps

```
.../jdk/jre/bin/java -cp [your_mongo_jar_file].jar
```

This command will return the version.